# C# Console: Keep program from closing until code is finished?

Tags: c#, console

How would I keep the console application from closing until the desired method has finished performing?

E.g. keep the console from closing until all client connections have been closed, all threads have been aborted and the client listener has stopped:
http://pastebin.com/CnN5HeR9

Comment: Please don't add tags to title and provide small sample code that demonstrates your problem inline in the post. Links to complete code are ok, but if you don't have code in the post there is no way such question will be useful for future readers.

Comment: The code itself is irrelevant, since what I am asking for doesn't directly relate to the question. It's an added bonus to show what I am using this for.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **Threads** you can do this

```
Thread th=new Thread(SomeMethod);
th.Start();
th.Join();//<-------------- this will make the console wait this thread until it end execution then proceed to the next instruction
Console.WriteLine("Thread Has Exited");
```

Hope it Helps :)
**Yaser**

Comment: That doesn't help too much, since I'll also need sockets to close as well. Any sort of code that can be used on a method in order to keep the console from closing?

Comment: as a workaround create a thread that keep checking on array of sockets statuses and while not all sockets exited keep the thread running ,meanwhile the console is waiting for this thread using `Join`

Comment: Hope it helps you out :)